# Populate NSMutableArrays to custom sections

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, ios5, tableview

Want to populate two `NSMutableArray`s to 2 Custom Sections of `tableView`;

I have two `NSMutableArray`s with events and I want to split them to now and today sections.

For the first section:

I want to remove events from nowEvents Array and place them into my frist section.

```
EventClass *event = [appDelegate.nowEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`event.startTime` is the start time of my event

`event.endTime` is the end time of my event

For 2nd section:
Remove the events that are happening now

```
EventClass *event = [appDelegate.todayEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

What I'd like to know is `numberOfRowsInSection` method, how it would look like and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (here I've tried `NSInteger section = [indexPath section]; if (section == 0) { } if (section == 1) {}` - but what about if I won't have an event that is happening now ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return [appDelegate.nowEvents count];
        case 1:
            return [appDelegate.todayEvents count];    
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            EventClass *nowEvent = [appDelegate.nowEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            //set up cell to display this event
            break;
        case 1:
            EventClass *todayEvent = [appDelegate.todayEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            //set up cell to display this event
            break;    
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

If you don't have an event happening now then your nowEvent array will be empty so in the numberOfRowsInSection will return 0 and therefore the cellForRowAtIndexPath won't be called as there is nothing to display. Hope this helps.

Comment: It won't display in raw but it will display my header section, which is has a custom image and I don't want to be displayed if I don't have any event in that section

Comment: So in your - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section; just have the following if  if([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]<=0) return 0;

Comment: actually its in my - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section method; if I place the if condition here, my app crashes

Comment: If you set the height to 0 the viewForHeaderInSection shouldn't be called for that section you can test this by printing out the sections that viewForHeaderInSection is requested for by using NSLog to output the section passed in.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 1 or 2 sections in your table view depending on the case, then in your numberOfRowsInSection you check if there are any events now (if they aren't then you drop that section). So Your ifs would be something like

```
BOOL eventsNow = YES/NO;
if (section == 0 && eventsNow) { } 
if (section == 0 && !eventsNow) { } 
if (section == 1 && eventsNow) { }
if (section == 1 && !eventsNow) { /* This case shouldn't happen so assert or throw ...*/ }
```